# Display SplitLayoutPanel and it's children elements

Tags: google-apps-script

I can't seem to make a SplitLayoutPanel display it's children elements.  GAS seems to support this class as it's noted in the documentation.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_splitlayoutpanel

Here's my attempt at the code.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  My assumption is this gives the user a splitter that they can drag to resize the panels (which is ideal for what I'm going for.  A left side panel with a right side panel with more details.

```
        function doGet(e) { 
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  //code goes here   

  var mainPanel = app.createSplitLayoutPanel().setId('mainPanel')
    .setVisible(true);
  app.add(mainPanel);

   var eastPanel = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('eastPanel');
  eastPanel.add(app.createLabel('eastPanel loaded'));
  mainPanel.addEast(eastPanel, 500);

  var westPanel = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('westPanel');
  westPanel.add(app.createLabel('westPanel loaded'));
  mainPanel.addWest(westPanel, 500);


  return app;
}
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single line `mainPanel.setSize('100%', '100%');` is missed. The following code works.

```
function doGet(e) { 
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  //code goes here   

  var mainPanel = app.createSplitLayoutPanel().setId('mainPanel')
    .setVisible(true);
  mainPanel.setSize('100%', '100%');
  app.add(mainPanel);

   var eastPanel = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('eastPanel');
  eastPanel.add(app.createLabel('eastPanel loaded'));
  mainPanel.addEast(eastPanel, 500);

  var westPanel = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('westPanel');
  westPanel.add(app.createLabel('westPanel loaded'));
  mainPanel.addWest(westPanel, 500);

  return app;
}
```

Comment: thanks @megabyte1024.  that was the missing link...I wish the documentation was a bit more clear on these items.  Appreciate the help.